# Error when clicking on the Edit Control Box (ECB)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

In a sharepoint project, on some lists when i click on the ECB i get a error message:

> This item is no longer available. It may have been deleted by another user. Click 'OK' to refresh the page.

I've done some research and found out that Microsoft has a hotfix for this problem, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2405789. But, it says that this hotfix is for Sharepoint Foundation.

My question is, can i use this KB on a Sharepoint Server env. or i need to find the specific KB for Server (which i didn't find).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However, you might want to take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2394320 is the SharePoint Server 2010 Cumulative Update which includes the hotfix you are looking for along with several others and that was released on same day.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint 2010 Standard or Enterprise, which it sounds like you are, you will need to apply the SharePoint Foundations Hot fixes/patches as well.  I also have been to told it is a best practice to install the foundation hotfixes first than move to SharePoint 2010.